# How do I instantiate a variable of a container containing type inside a template function or class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, decltype

How do I instantiate a variable of a container containing type inside a template function or class ?

I added typename on the recommendation of  [dependent scope; need typename in front;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874535/dependent-scope-need-typename-in-front)

But still could not make it work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
void crazy_func_byvalue(T data){
    typename decltype(data)::value_type var; //typename added here
    cout<< typeid(var).name();
    cout<<endl;
    return;
}

template<class T>
void crazy_func_byaddress(T& data){
    typename decltype(data)::value_type var;
    cout<< typeid(var).name();
    cout<<endl;
    return;
}

class test{
};

int main(){
    std::array<double,12> var1={1593,-88517,14301,3200,6,-15099,3200,5881,-2593,11,57361,-92990};
    decltype(var1)::value_type x;
    std::vector<test> var2;
    crazy_func_byvalue(var1);
    crazy_func_byvalue(var2);
    crazy_func_byaddress(var1); //error: 'std::array<double, 12ul>&' is not a class, struct, or union type
    crazy_func_byaddress(var2); //error: 'std::vector<test>&' is not a class, struct, or union type

    //cout<<"It is working here";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the reference (with `std::remove_reference`)

```
template<class T>
void crazy_func_byaddress(T& data){
    typename std::remove_reference<decltype(data)>::type::value_type var;
    cout<< typeid(var).name();
    cout<<endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked, i was trying to do the same, but was not able to figure out the exact way to do it.

Comment: @KinanAlSarmini - Obvious; but the OP show us two different functions where uses `decltype()`; the first one works, the second one doesn't. He can use `T::value_type` in both but is important (IMHO) to show how to use `decltype` with reference variables.