# Accsess nested class from outside in C++

Tags: c++, class, nested, inner-classes

Hello I want to access a nested class from other class.

```
class OutSideClass
{
public:
    class InSideClass
    {
       ...
    };
    friend class InSideClass;
};

class Other
{
    InSideClass x; // This doesn't work
};
```

The class InSideClass is a public class so I don't understand why can I access it from outside

I also want to access

```
template <typename T>
class OutSideClass
{
public:
    class InSideClass
    {
        class InSideClassIterator
        {

        };
    };


public:
    class Other
    {
    OutSideClass<T>::InSideClass::InSideClassIterator x;
    };


};
```

Comment: Pleasea review whether you have omitted a "not" somewhere in your question...

Comment: `OutSideClass::InSideClass x;` should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class `InSideClass` is inside `OutSideClass`, so you have to specify so.

```
class Other
{
    OutSideClass::InSideClass x; // This should work
};
```

In the second case, the declaration is inside `OutSideClass`, so you should remove `OutSideClass<T>::` from the declaration.

Also `typename` seems to be required according to these:

- [c++ - dependent scope; need typename in front; - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874535/dependent-scope-need-typename-in-front)
- [c++ - Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

  ```
    class Other
    {
    typename InSideClass::InSideClassIterator x;
    };
  ```

Comment: Can you explain what should I do when OutSideClass has template. For example

`template <typename T>
class OutSideClass`

Comment: @user75453 `OutSideClass<something>::InSideClass x;`. `something` should what you want like `int`.

Comment: I have edited my question can you explain how to acess that. It seems like in that case it does'nt works

Comment: @user75453 Add template argument for `OutSideClass` like my previous reply.

Comment: @user75453 The declaration is inside `OutSideClass` in this case, so `OutSideClass<T>::` should be removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221878/discussion-between-user75453-and-mikecat).